# i have some data into this format i want to seprate user id and insert it into table

Tags: sql, json

```json
{
  "PK_ID" : 0,
  "Group_Id" : 39,
  "Group_Name" : null,
  "Admin_User_Id" : 0,
  "DisplayName" : null,
  "Sms" : true,
  "Email" : false,
  "WhatsApp" : false,
  "UpdatedBy" : 28,
  "CreatedBy" : 28,
  "users" : [ {
    "UserID" : "5"
  }, {
    "UserID" : "7"
  }, {
    "UserID" : "22"
  }, {
    "UserID" : "23"
  }, {
    "UserID" : "24"
  }, {
    "UserID" : "25"
  }, {
    "UserID" : "33"
  }, {
    "UserID" : "45"
  }, {
    "UserID" : "46"
  }, {
    "UserID" : "47"
  } ],
  "MailOfficial" : null,
  "CC" : null,
  "BCC" : null,
  "EmailSubject" : null,
  "EmailContent" : null,
  "MessageText" : null,
  "WhatsAppText" : null,
  "SpName" : null,
  "MobileNo" : null,
  "TypeOfReport" : null
}
```

i want to seprate user id and want to insert into table

Comment: Please share the expected Result and the code you are using. With just the JSON object it's impossible to help

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @json NVarChar(max) = N'{"PK_ID":0,"Group_Id":39,"Group_Name":null,"Admin_User_Id":0,"DisplayName":null,"Sms":true,"Email":false,"WhatsApp":false,"UpdatedBy":28,"CreatedBy":28,"users":[{"UserID":"5"},{"UserID":"7"},{"UserID":"22"},{"UserID":"23"},{"UserID":"24"},{"UserID":"25"},{"UserID":"33"},{"UserID":"45"},{"UserID":"46"},{"UserID":"47"}],"MailOfficial":null,"CC":null,"BCC":null,"EmailSubject":null,"EmailContent":null,"MessageText":null,"WhatsAppText":null,"SpName":null,"MobileNo":null,"TypeOfReport":null}';

select * into temp from (SELECT * FROM OpenJson(@json))dr

declare @str nvarchar(max)=(select value from temp where [key]='users')

select replace(replace(value,'{"UserID":"',''),'"}','') as ID from OpenJson( @str)
Drop table temp

Can you please check the above answer with a temporary table solution?

Comment: That is non-standard SQL, please specify for which database product this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/), you can use this:

```
insert into target_table (user_id) 
select u.item ->> 'UserID'
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.the_column -> 'users') as u(item)
```